# Match Everything Between Tags That Contain Key

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a (sed style) regex that will match every instance of the word "HAWK" and the closest surrounding item tags, i.e. `<item> ... HAWK ... </item>`, where the ellipsis may be text or other tags (but not the item tag).

So far I've tried lazy match-all: `<item>(.*?)HAWK(.*?)<\/item>`, and find that this works well for catching everything between HAWK and the closing item tag, but matches over many nested opening `<item>` tags, and so winds up getting too much.

I think using look-behind might help but I've had problems getting this to work properly also. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of xml parsers, please don't rewrite them poorly from scratch.

Comment: I'm implementing the regex with sed.

Comment: What is your current `sed` expression?

Comment: s/<item>(.*?)HAWK(.*?)<\/item>//g. But as I explained this does not achieve what I want. Why does this matter? It's the regex that I'm concerned with and I don't think the logic is going to change because I'm using a UNIX flavour.

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find the "closest tag" using `sed` style expressions, you can try

```
/<item>[^>]*HAWK[^<]*<\/item>\)/
```

This works in 'regular sed'. Basically, by matching anything that is not a closing bracket before HAWK, and anything that is not an opening bracket after HAWK, it 'simulates' the non-greedy quantifier `.*?`.

But it is usually not a good idea to try to parse XML etc with regex - a 'real parser' is much more robust. But hey, you asked.

Comment: Yep, I did, and I really appreciate you answering my original question anyway.